# How to simulate a small game as a interactive website?

Tags: web, simulation, interactive

I've decided to start a project so that I can learn some coding. I'm pretty new to coding(Pretty decent at html/css) so I've no idea what coding language to use, but I'm committed to learn and finish the project, just need some orientation.

I'm trying to make an interactive website, that's gonna simulate a small game/chat called "Habbo"(It uses mostly the pointer to do everthing). I want this interactive website just to simulate the moving in the game and for example when I click an object a window with some info, image, etc would pop up.

1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEPsx.png
2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBEWF.gif

The first image is what I want to show on the website, It's basically a room with furnitures of the game and second picture is how I need to move over the room.

Edit: In this http://habbo.wikia.com/wiki/Habbo_Wiki website at about half way a room with furniture is shown and you can click on the furniture but can't move. I wanna make it so the the user can move all around the room and do different tasks. I hope i'm not confusing anyone.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What lenguage do I need to use to be able to simulate the game and make it a interactive website. Sorry for misleading title. I forgot to change it :/

Comment: Just found out this: http://www.spritely.net/ I don't know if jQuery is the best way to go... I'm also considering Java. Need some advice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Java. Applets are too heavy and generally unwelcomed by users and expecially browsers!

You can use Flash. have you ever seen a Flash game? It is provided as a plugin in all the browsers, it is welcomed and accepted by nearly all the users.
So, start to learn it.

[Here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/10/29/flash-game-creation-tutorial-part-1/) you can find one out of a dozens of free Flash tutorials.